# How do you get variable information in the editor for actionscript/flex

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a flex project with some actionscript files and when I mouse over variables in the class I would have expected information about that variable to popup like in other IDEs, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I h ave the show quick doc on mouse over set to true and that works for Flash/Air runtime libraries and classes but nothing for my local stuff.

The quick doc stuff also doesn't seem to work for actionscript with a script tag in an mxml file unless I use the manual ctrl+q shortcut (just doesn't work on mouse hover)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is active by default in Adobe Flash Builder and Flex for ActionScript 3.0 native classes and the components included in it like functions, variables, constant, etc.

To get this feature activated for the variable you create in your projects, you shall write comments over the lines of declaration of such variables you want their description to appear over.

This is the right format:

```
/*
 * Your comment about the variable or the justDoIt function
 */
private function justDoIt():void
{
    return;
}
```

Now, whenever you call this function from any place in your code along he entire project, you'll be able to see the comment you wrote before it.